# What are the relationships between bound morpheme and affix?

Tags: words, morphemes, affixes

Anderson's Essentials of Linguistics introduces bound morphemes in

> A morpheme is the smallest form that has meaning. Some
> morphemes are free: they can appear in isolation. (This means that
> some words are also morphemes.) But some morphemes can only
> ever appear when they’re attached to something else; these are called
> bound morphemes.

and affixes (prefixes, suffixes, infixes) in

> If a word is made up of just one morpheme,
> like banana, swim, hungry, then we say that it’s morphologically
> simple, or monomorphemic.
> But many words have more than one morpheme in them: they’re
> morphologically complex or polymorphemic. In English,
> polymorphemic words are usually made up of a root plus one or more
> affixes.  The root morpheme is the single morpheme that determines
> the core meaning of the word. In most cases in English, the root is
> a morpheme that could be free. The affixes are bound morphemes.
> English has affixes that attach to the end of a root; these are called
> suffixes, like in books, teaching, happier, hopeful, singer. And English
> also has affixes that attach to the beginning of a word, called prefixes,
> like in unzip, reheat, disagree, impossible.

Is a bound morpheme an affix? If not, what kind of bound morpheme is an affix, and what kind is not?

Is an affix a bound morpheme?
If not, what kind of affix is a bound morpheme, and what kind is not?

Thanks.

Comment: The [Wikipedia article on bound and free morphemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bound_and_free_morphemes) gives some examples of bound morphemes that aren’t affixes – the most common type is _cranberry morphemes_, named after the bound morpheme _cran_.